# Unable to iterate images from database

Tags: java, html, jsp, iterator

I am fetching `src` of images from DB and trying to put it into the JSP page but only one image is loading and rest 2 are not loading

code:

```
<%  
    Iterator<product> itr = list.iterator(); 
    while(itr.hasNext())
    { 
      p=itr.next();  
      String price=p.getPrice();
      String img=p.getImg();
      String pname=p.getPname();                       
   %>   
      <script>
        document.getElementById("image").src="<%=img %>";  
      </script>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="<%=img%>" id="image"/>
         <h2><%=pname%></h2>

        <p>Price: <em>Rs <%=price%></em>
        </p>
        <button class="add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button>
    </div>  
     <% } %>
```

but I am getting the below output :
[image: screenshot of the jsp page]

java DB code:

```
public List<product> getProducts(String brand)
{ 
   List<product> prod=new ArrayList<product>();
  try
  {
   conn = obj.connect();
   String sql="select product.product_name , product.price , product.image_url "
           + "from category , product "
           + "where product.category_id=category.category_id and product.product_brand like 'LG%'";
    cs=conn.createStatement();  
   rs=cs.executeQuery(sql);
     while(rs.next())
     {
         product p=new product();
       p.setPname(rs.getString(1));
       p.setPrice(rs.getString(2));
       p.setImg(rs.getString(3));
       prod.add(p);  
     }

  }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception k)
    {
        k.printStackTrace();
    }
  return prod;
}

}
```

Comment: You should really have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/3419894)

Comment: @JonK .. i will surely read this ..thanks a lot

Comment: for what brand you want to fetch image

Comment: @xrcwrn .. i have added the same image for nexus 3 , nexus 5 , nexus 7

Comment: but you are finding 'LG%' each time. not for brand as nexus

Answer (score 0):

```
<%  
  Iterator<product> itr = list.iterator(); 
  while(itr.hasNext())
  { 
    p=itr.next();  
    String price=p.getPrice();
    String img=p.getImg();
    String pname=p.getPname();
%>    
<div class="item">
<img src="<%=img%>" alt="<%=img%>"/>
<h2><%=pname%></h2>

<p>Price: <em>Rs <%=price%></em></p>
<button class="add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
<% } %>
```

`document.getElementById("image").src="<%=img %>";` is overwriting the first img tag

Comment: i removed the `document.getElementById("image").src="<%=img %>";` .. now it is not showing image for any item

Comment: src="${img}" try this

Comment: it dosent allow this also ... i guess i need to start using JSTL

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm here it userse             <font color="green" size="<%= fontSize %>"> so it shoud also work with img

Answer (score 0):

i finally found an answer ... it may be a workaround but it still works !!!

`<div style="background: url(<%=img%>);"></div>`

just added the above in my code .. no need to use the `<img>` tag